# Significance threshold for emmeans contrasts

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, lsmeans

I am using binomial GAMs with `mgcv` in R to model binary species presence on a hydrophone against environmental (chlorophyll-a concentration, sea-surface temperature, sea-level, vessel presence) and categorical temporal covariates (season and photoperiod):

```
M <- gam(Species ~ s(Chla, bs="ts") + s(SST,bs="ts") + 
                   s(SLEV, bs="ts") + Season + Photoperiod + Vessel, 
                   data=Hydrophone, family='binomial', 
                   method = "ML")
```

My goal with this model is inference; I would like to determine which covariates had a significant effect on the probability of species detection and whether the probability of species detection was different across factor levels for the categorical variables. For the former, I am planning on using `anova.gam` and am identifying significant variables by having p-values < 0.001. I am choosing a high significance threshold of 0.001 mainly based on Zuur et al. (2009, p. 68):

> You can safely make biological statements based on smoothers with a p-value of 0.001 (or smaller) or a p-value of 0.1 (or larger), but be very careful with smoothers for which p is just below the magical 0.05 level

For comparing the probability of species presence across factor levels, I am using `contrast` from the `emmeans` library with the `method="pairwise"` argument. **My question is whether I should apply a similarly high significance threshold (i.e. 0.001) to my `contrast` tests as I did for my `anova.gam` tests?**

I understand that part of the reason for using a high significance threshold for `anova.gam` is that the p-values are approximate, but am not sure if this applies to the `contrast` test too. I understand that assessing significance using a rigid significance threshold is problematic but feel the need to set an informed threshold *a priori* to remain objective.